# Resources for Trending

Tags: reference-request, regression

Suppose that we are looking at the amount people spend on groceries (the actual data is something similar), the company I work for wants me to see whether there is a way to predict people's future spending on groceries. Currently, we don't do anything other than exponential trending in excel. If I want to improve this process by using data like CPI, Inflation and also use other trending methods and decide on which method is the best, is there a text book or online resource that I can learn from? I'm a math graduate but haven't really done any regression other than one applied math course so I'm looking for a textbook or two you would recommend that I can learn by myself. Ideally, it is applicative (I know R and SAS and SQL). Also, I believe that the company data is very noisy. Given that we've previously only been using excel, I'm not looking for something PHD level but rather something a masters graduate can learn and work through.

Comment: if I had to do that today, I'ld try to find if there are precursor points of sell, then first looking for internal correlations. *Shift* would be the keyword. After, it is the wet finger in the wind theory, because you need years to validate models that are in general efficient only for periods more or less short.